Damage encrypted APFS recovery ( superblock or keybag might be overwritten?

enter image description hereMy external drive(Transcend 2TB HDD) with 1.5TB APFS encrypted volume, there are many photo library files in it. One day I used 0.5TB fat32 part as windows 11 install disk, after I finish setup, I found that HDD drive only have 32GB, and 1.5TB APFS encrypted volume has gone!!!! I use r-studio and UFS explorer in windows and also try Drat 0.1.3 to scan to find back superblock and keybag, but have no luck. How can I get back pics and photo library in APFS????I think it might be the same issue because I try to find recovery company but expensive and try hex to see metadata inside it seem garbied code???I know my original password~~enter image description here
enter image description here


I’m not sure what you are showing in the images - of course the mount fails due to the error condition and why did you select those hex offsets? I would presume diskutil and gpt text output to be more helpful for someone to offer a path other than decide if paying an expert is worth it.  I would not try the gpt recover until you’re sure someone has a good plan to not make the problem worse…
